# How to control the download url for dotNetFx35setup.exe without using the Visual Studio bootstrapper

Tags: .net, installation, bootstrapping

Previously I've used to Visual Studio 2008 setup.bin to generate a bootstrapper. I had some issues with it which were difficult to resolve and turned to [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com). One great thing with the VS 2008 generated bootstrapper, was that I was able to control the download location for the .NET framework. By using the MSBuild task I could specify the componentsLocation:

```
<GenerateBootstrapper 
    ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="MyApp" 
    ApplicationUrl="http://$(InstallerHost)$(DownloadUrl)"
    BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" 
    CopyComponents="True" ComponentsLocation="Relative" 
    OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" 
    Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\"  />
```

Here I'm able to use the ComponentsLocation="Relative" and the bootstrapper would download from our own web server - which is what I want. When I no longer have the VS 2008 bootstrapper, I would like to have the same feature. The new boostrapper downloads the dotNetFx35setup.exe from a defined server, but the problem is that this ".NET bootstrapper" connects to Microsoft's servers for downloading the needed packages. Trying to run the following command:

```
dotNetFx35setup.exe /?
```

did not show any options to control the download location. The web server will contain the package structure which the Windows SDK (v6.0A) has within the Bootstrapper\Packages directory. The structure looks like this:

```
Packages
    DotNetFX
    DotNetFX30
    DotNetFX35
    DotNetFx35Client
    DotNetFx35SP1
    .....
```

When I state a dependency to the .NET Framework 3.5, the DotNetFX35 directory structure gets copied into the bin/Debug directory. I've copied this directory onto the web server and it looks like this:

```
DotNetFX35
    dotNetFX20
    dotNetFX30
    dotNetFX35
        x64
            netfx35_x64.exe
        x86
            netfx35_x86.exe
    dotNetMSP
    dotNetFx35setup.exe
```

The other directories contains mainly MSI, MSP and MSU files. So any pointers on how to control downloading of the .NET framework. Shouldn't I use the dotNetFx35setup.exe file? If not - which should I use?

Comment: Wow, this is the Mother of all Really Bad Ideas.  Are you really going to keep this server running for the next 20 years?  Provide five nines up-time guarantee?  Keep it updated with security patches and service packs?  Why?

Comment: You assume that this is an application which is going to be served in the public - which is not the case. And the speed up with being able to near LAN speed is definitely worth it! It's not in house so we cannot use a regular file server. MS added this for a reason - there's definitely valid use cases for this.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to use the .NET Framework 3.5 full package.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe

You can use the InstallerEditor in dotNetInstaller to add the "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" component from the menu.

See the code the InstallerEditor adds [here](https://github.com/dotnetinstaller/dotnetinstaller/blob/36567509faef246ce95af6d567c945ff0bb90a22/InstallerEditor/wizardcomponents.xml#L135-L140).

It's also copied here for convenience:

```
  <component command="&quot;#TEMPPATH\dotNetRuntime_Download_#PID\dotnetfx35setup.exe&quot; &quot;/norestart /q&quot;" returncodes_reboot="3010" hide_window="False" disable_wow64_fs_redirection="False" execution_method="CreateProcess" id="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" display_name="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" os_filter_min="winXPsp2" type="cmd" mustreboot="False" must_reboot_required="False" allow_continue_on_error="False" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="True" required_uninstall="False" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="False" note="English - WebSetup - .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 for all operating system since Windows XP SP2 (Install check)" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="False" show_progress_dialog="False" show_cab_dialog="False">
    <installedcheck path="Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5" fieldname="Install" fieldvalue="1" defaultvalue="False" fieldtype="REG_DWORD" comparison="match" rootkey="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" wowoption="NONE" type="check_registry_value" description="Installed Check" />
    <downloaddialog dialog_caption="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 - Download Components" dialog_message="Press 'Start' to download the required components for installing Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1." dialog_message_downloading="Download in progress. Please wait..." dialog_message_copying="Files are downloaded. Please wait ..." dialog_message_connecting="Connecting ..." dialog_message_sendingrequest="Sending request ..." autostartdownload="False" buttonstart_caption="Start" buttoncancel_caption="Cancel">
      <download componentname="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" sourceurl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/6/1/061F001C-8752-4600-A198-53214C69B51F/dotnetfx35setup.exe" destinationpath="#TEMPPATH\dotNetRuntime_Download_#PID" destinationfilename="dotnetfx35setup.exe" alwaysdownload="True" clear_cache="False" />
    </downloaddialog>
  </component>
```

Comment: I am aware that I need the full package, but you did not focus on how to resolve this is dotNetInstaller which is the question.

Comment: Here is an example component configuration for .net 3.5 sp1 (x86): http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=80420.  Just change the sourceUrl to your custom url.